# I need help implementing a (very simple) "algorithm". Where should I ask?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I think there are several options and SO will probably not be the best place to ask. But I would like to understand the pros and cons.

For context, I want to check several web services and wait until they are all working. This seems like a list iteration, where one deletes the working web services. Of course, we cannot delete items from list while looping them.

Comment: Write some code that works, and then post the resulting work to Code Review.

Comment: You will want to break down a problem.  For instance, even in this problem statement, there are at least two issues, one is [removing an item during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) and [how to check if a server is up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867184/how-to-check-whether-my-server-is-up-and-running-using-python).  Make sure to study and understand the small problems first.

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow is the correct place to ask. However, I can pretty well guarantee you that it has been asked before, for your language. Please search first, and do not ask duplicate questions.

For example, the canonical version of the question for Python is [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406). It has over 800k views and hundreds of linked duplicates.

If, for some reason, you needed to ask a new question (say, for example, that you're trying out a new, experimental programming language and trying to find the few other people using it), it is important to focus the question on the **actual problem, not** the task you are trying to implement. Here, that means: the question is not about checking the web services (you apparently know how to do that for individual services), or about how to repeat the "repeat the check until the list is empty" step, but about the actual filtering of the list.

If you encountered a concrete problem with a naive approach (in your case: if you wrote a simple loop, and either encountered some kind of error or found that not everything was removed as expected), then consider including an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, if you simply want to know the canonical way to solve the problem (for example, if you suspect that you shouldn't have to write a loop explicitly in the first place), that might not be productive, as it shifts the focus away from how-to and towards debugging.

Comment: I didn't want to assume my way to look at the problem (iterate and remove items from the same list) was the best approach. That's why I wanted to ask how to solve the generic problem, and not how to remove items from a list (which would assume my approach was the best/only one).

Comment: At some point you have to specify something. If the task description *isn't* some combination of "iterate over a list" and "remove items from a list", and the problem *isn't* some variation of "trying to remove something during the iteration causes an error or the wrong result", then what **is** being asked? But more importantly: don't ask a question that's about checking web services, if you know how to check web services, that knowledge isn't helping you solve the overall problem, and doesn't help explain what that problem is.

Comment: The only natural conclusion is that *you would be running into the same issue, whether or not you had to check web services in order to complete the task*. Therefore, the question is *not about* those web services.

Answer (score 6):

Honestly it sounds like your *algorithm* is already implemented.

- Gather list of websites
- For each site in the list:

  - Check to see if it is live
- Once all sites are done, terminate the program

What you may have trouble expressing here is your *implementation*, or in other words, ***how to build or write it***.  This is likely because, quite bluntly, **there are *a million* ways** to go about this.

Depending on your skill level, you might want to reach for a language you're familiar with to poll sites.  Or, you could get more sophisticated and use something like Ansible to help build out playbooks to do this thing as well.  There's also something to be said about, if you are in control of the sites, using some kind of monitor tool or monitor service makes this a trivial problem to solve, too.  May cost something, though, but sometimes it's cheaper to spend money than to spend time on the solution, because `time == money`.

Asking this question in the site is fine though, but you have to be ***very*** precise.

- What language or framework are you attempting to leverage to solve this problem?
- What have you already tried and what have you already written?
- What is the condition that defines when a site is "up", and how do you inspect it?  (Note: pinging an IP address doesn't mean that the actual web service is live or able to support traffic.)

If you just posted your question as-is, it'd probably get downvoted and closed as being too broad, because it is.  There are so many ways to live checks on websites that there's no one right answer we could give you, and we're not meant to turn this question into a free-for-all kind of discussion/experiment session.

Comment: Same comment as above. I didn't want to assume this was the right way to go, Maybe there was some other approach I never heard/thought about. That was probably my main question.

Comment: @RobertoMorávia:  We can't help you brainstorm a solution.  There's [no right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to "what other approaches are there".  What we expect of you is to pick **an** approach, implement it and let us know where you're stuck in the confines of that specific approach.  That makes your question more concrete and answerable.

Comment: Sometimes in leetcode I find that the accepted answer is easier and faster than mine. And I didn't think of that. So, my question was where to ask that kind of questions. Maybe not SO. Fine. But surely there are other places. Maybe someone knows one and can share.

Comment: @RobertoMorávia:  Yeah, Stack Overflow probably isn't what you're looking for then.  We're more about getting answers to an objective question, not exploring different approaches for problems.